# custom view edittext has setontouchlistener called on it but does not override performclick

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What is the solution of this issue? App force close when click on text box (etPhoneNumber) please view below image of android studio for understanding error.

Custom view has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick If a View that overrides `onTouchEvent` or uses an `OnTouchListener` does not also implement `performClick` and call it when clicks are detected, the View may not handle accessibility actions properly.

Logic handling the click actions should ideally be placed in `View#performClick` as some accessibility services invoke `performClick` when a click action should occur.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlVX9.jpg

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.ccp)
    CountryCodePicker ccp;
    @BindView(R.id.etPhoneNumber)
    EditText etPhoneNumber;
    @BindView(R.id.etMessage)
    EditText etMessage;
    @BindView(R.id.fab)
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    @BindView(R.id.rlMainView)
    RelativeLayout rlMainView;

    ArrayList<Calldetails> calldetailsArrayList;
    private static final int MISSED_CALL_TYPE = 0;
    CallListAdapter callListAdapter;
    RuntimePermission runtimePermission;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

        runtimePermission = new RuntimePermission();
       /* Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg);
        BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bmImg);
        background.setGravity(Gravity.);
        rlMainView.setBackgroundDrawable(background);*/


        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String phone = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();
                String messge = etMessage.getText().toString().trim();
                String cc = ccp.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus();
                if (phone.length() < 10) {
                    Toast.makeText((Context) MainActivity.this, "Please add valid Phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (messge.length() <= 0) {
                    Toast.makeText((Context) MainActivity.this, "Please enter your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    openWhatsApp(cc, phone, messge);
                }
            }
        });

        etPhoneNumber.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
                final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
                final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= (etPhoneNumber.getRight() - etPhoneNumber.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                        // your action here

                        runtimePermission.ask(MainActivity.this, new RuntimePermission.OnRequestPermissionsResultListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onGranted(String permission[], int requestCode) {
                                FatchcallRecord();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDenied(String permission[], int requestCode) {

                            }

                        },new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, 110, "Phone call permission need for view your call history","OK","CANCEL");

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        runtimePermission.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
    }

    private void FatchcallRecord() {
        calldetailsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:aa");
        Uri contacts = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(contacts, null, null, null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC limit 200;");

        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        sb.append("Call Details :");

        try {
            if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    Calldetails calldetails;
                    String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
                    String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
                    String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
                    Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
                    String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
                    String dir = null;
                    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
                    switch (dircode) {

                        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                            dir = "OUTGOING";
                            break;

                        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                            dir = "INCOMING";
                            break;

                        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                            dir = "MISSED";
                            break;
                    }

                    calldetails = new Calldetails(phNumber,callType,formatter.format(callDayTime),callDuration);
                    calldetailsArrayList.add(calldetails);
                    sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                            + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + formatter.format(callDayTime)
                            + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
                    sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
                }
            }
            managedCursor.close();
            showCallList();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("###",sb.toString());
    }

    public void showCallList(){


        final Dialog dialogBuilder = new Dialog((Context) this);
        dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        dialogBuilder.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_call_list);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialogBuilder.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        dialogBuilder.show();
        dialogBuilder.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

        callListAdapter = new CallListAdapter(MainActivity.this,calldetailsArrayList,etPhoneNumber,dialogBuilder);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) dialogBuilder.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(callListAdapter);

        TextView tvCancle = (TextView) dialogBuilder.findViewById(R.id.tvCancle);
        tvCancle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogBuilder.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //    https://mobikul.com/sending-message-application-whatsapp-number/
    public void openWhatsApp(String cc, String phone, String messge) {
        try {
            String toNumber = "" + cc + "" + phone; // Replace with mobile phone number without +Sign or leading zeros.


            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("whatsapp://send/?text=" + URLEncoder.encode(messge, "UTF-8") + "&phone=" + toNumber));
//            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + toNumber + "&text=" + messge));
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect touch and click separate then you should use **SimpleGestureListner**
Which gives you touch event as well as onSingleClick.